# How to resolve getting data from observable

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have a problem getting data from an observable, when I use subscribe in the method
example:

```
this.service.getProducts().subscribe(.....) ,
```

it returns to me:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3011/clinic/products' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

and the data is not listed

Data Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  public url = 'http://localhost:3010';
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}    

    getProducts(){
        debugger;
        return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.url}/clinic/products`);
    }

    authenticate(data){
      return this.http.post(`${this.url}/accounts/authenticate`,data);
    }

    saveProducts(data){
      debugger;
      return this.http.post(`${this.url}/clinic/products`,data);
    }

        
    
  
}
```

Products Page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { $ } from 'protractor';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.services';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-page',
  templateUrl: './products-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-page.component.css']
})
export class ProductsPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public products$!: Observable<Product[]>;
  public form: FormGroup;
  public prodId: string = uuidv4();
    

  constructor(
    private service: DataService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router
    ) { 
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        prodName:['', ],
        prodId:[this.prodId, ],
        slug:[this.prodId,],
        prodBrand: ['', ],
        prodMeasurement: ['',],
        prodAmount: ['',],
        prodVolume: ['',],
        prodWeight: ['',],
        prodPrice: ['',],
        prodActive:[true,]
 
      });
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products$ = this.service.getProducts();    

  }

  submit(){
    debugger;
    this.service.saveProducts(this.form.value)
        .subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            this.toastr.success(data.message,'Teste');            
           
            debugger;
            let modalProducts = document.getElementById('modalProducts');
            modalProducts.hidden = true;
            this.router.navigate['/clinic/products'];
            this.ngOnInit();
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    
      
  }

}
```

JSON sent by API

```
{
    "dados":{
        "Filial":"teste",
        "Cnpj":"12345678901234"
    },
    "produtos": [
        {
            "prodName": "Creme 02",
            "prodBrand": "Mary Kay",
            "prodMeasurement": "unidade",
            "prodAmount": "1",
            "prodVolume": "",
            "prodWeight": "",
            "prodPrice": "150"
        },
        {
            "prodName": "Creme 03",
            "prodBrand": "Mary Kay",
            "prodMeasurement": "unidade",
            "prodAmount": "1",
            "prodVolume": "",
            "prodWeight": "",
            "prodPrice": "154"
        },
        {
            "prodName": "Creme 05",
            "prodBrand": "Mary Kay",
            "prodMeasurement": "unidade",
            "prodAmount": "1",
            "prodVolume": "",
            "prodWeight": "",
            "prodPrice": "565"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And do you think the server _does_ set the appropriate CORS headers?

Comment: You have to allow CORS inside your Backend Code.

Comment: when I try only this.products= this.service.getProducts(); without subscribe this error does not occur, but I can't get the "products"

Comment: using postman the error also does not occur and returns data correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@crossOrigin = (origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

in service class its port '3011' you have use